# One box is not fitting in different screen resolutions

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I've been working on a one website for some time now. At main page I have box on the left that shows confessions and right next to that box I have another one which displays most liked confession. Now the box on the left is fitting screen awesome in every screen resolution, but the right one is going inside first when the screen resolution is lower. I will post pictures describing my problem. How can I achieve to both boxes fit good and when the screen resolution is lower I don't want them to become all messy. My screen is 1920x1080, and that box won't fit good if screen is 1900, so itll work just above 1900 width.

**My left box CSS:**

```
.confessbox { 
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, .3);
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 597px;
    float:right;

}

.confession {
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, .4);
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 3px 0;
    width: 578px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

**My right box CSS:**

```
.sidebox {
    float: right;
        left: -24%;
        margin-top: 3.4%;
        width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    top:20px;
    position: relative;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

My HTML inside those boxes are pretty big, so I'll just explain, **content inside left box goes like:**

```
<div class=container">
<div class="confessBox">
<div class="confession">

<!-- HERE GOES ALL ITS CONTENT -->

</div>
</div>
```

**Content inside right box just goes like:**

```
<div class="sidebox">

<!-- HERE GOES ALL ITS CONTENT -->

</div>
```

[On 1920x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufwcn.png)

[On 1024x600, and its only visible good on 1900 width and above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwvE2.png)

So I would like them to show both in one line no metter what is screen resolution, is that possible? I've tested some other sites and there everything is looking good even on low resolutions.

Comment: Can you please update the mock up how you want to design the page.

Comment: I want it to be same as in 1920x1080, thats the size on which I desinged website

Answer (score 1):

```
.leftsectionClassName,.rightsectionClassName{min-height:100vh}
```

**100vh** will occupy the fullscreen viewport hight. whatevet the resolution monitor use are using which will take queal height.

Hope it will be use full for you. if you have any doubt please let me know.

Comment: So I should add this to my left and right section, am I right?

Comment: It didnt helped, the sidebox is still changing its positions when I change resolution.

Comment: but this is pretty close, check it here http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//www.confessions.byethost31.com/&w=1920&h=1200&a=1 , its showing different just a little, what can I do to next?

Comment: @Aleksa please update your full html and CSS code And also share the expected design that you want . so that we can address and give the exact solution.

Comment: Can you give me your email so I can share a code with you? The code is really big tho, and If you're willing to help you can share email so I can share code with you and you can help, I still didint figure out whats the problem

Comment: @Aleksa you can use jsfiddle to upload your code .. there is you can find HTML, CSS, JS code editor separately, https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this you can try using css **media queries**
You can add specific css rules depending on the width of the screen.

This rule says for a window with a max-width of 1900px apply these styles:

```
@media (max-width:1900px) { 
.sidebox {
 left: auto; /*restore to default*/
 right: -24%; /*push it to the right more*/
}
 }
```

here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2b6oz8h/) I did if you want to test it there maybe.

w3schools has a page about media queries if you want to read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: It's not helping that much when I change different resolutions my box is still going left and right and It just cant stay in the same place on every resolution, dont know what im doing wrong